# nginx is replying with an error 403 after opening URL

Tags: nginx

When typing my URL "other-40.umwelt-campus.de" or just "localhost" I get `403 Forbidden` from nginx. But when typing the full path "other-40.umwelt-campus.de/MyDigitalHome/index.php" it perfectly redirects me.

The config looks like:

```
root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name localhost;

location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args/ =404;
        # proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        # proxy_http_version 1.1;
        # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        # proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

The directory structure looks like: `/var/www/html/MyDigitalHome/index.php`
Setting the root folder to `/var/www/html/MyDigitalHome/` ain't working too. 
If doing so it seems to have no permissions on the subfolder.

Comment: The 403 status usually means that an index file was not found in the specified directory. If the URI is `/` and the `root` is `/var/www/html`, then Nginx is looking for `/var/www/html/index.php`. If you change the `root` value, don't forget to restart Nginx and clear your browser cache between tests.

Comment: @RichardSmith I already tried to set the root to the subfolder. Also cleared the cache. But it couldn't find all of the subfolders.